# Closing a question now requires 3 close votes, not 5

Tags: support, status-completed, help-center

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes

> It takes 5 close votes from members of the community with the close vote privilege to close a question.

I believe it takes 3 now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've corrected the article to use the new variable for the number of close votes needed instead of an integrated number. Shows correctly now.